# Django: Using Func for unnest array of dicts and apply filters

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a model same as below:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    sub_items = ArrayField(JSONField(null=True), null=True, default=list)
    ...
```

The data on the `sub_items` store like below:

```
[
    {
        "dt": 159565990,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 75
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565990,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 100
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565990,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 80
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565910,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 100
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565920,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 100
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565940,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 20
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565950,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 50
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565972,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 10
        }
    },

    {
        "dt": 159565989,
        "task": {
            "description": "This is a task...",
            "progress": 100
        }
    },
]
```

Every array item contains "progress" key in dept and I need query for getting all items that progress is equal to 100.

I try fetching data by using below query:

```
Work.objects.annotate(xyz=models.functions.Cast(models.Func(models.F('history'), function='unnest'), JSONField())).filter(xyz__message__progress=100)
```

But django can't handle this query by below prompt:

> *** django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
>   Line 1: ..." WHERE ("x_sub_items"."status" = 0 AND ((unnest("x_...